# I'm using eclipse and creating BDD framework . In my runner file, Import cucumber.api is not resolved How to fix this issue?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, cucumber, pom.xml

I'm using eclipse and creating BDD framework . In my runner file, Import cucumber.api is not resolved How to fix this issue?
[Attached test runner class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0etmq.png)

This is my POM file. I think my jar file has some kind of issue which i'm not able to figure out as I'm beginner in automation.

```
<dependencies>
<!-- To download Selenium-java Jar file-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>
<!-- To download junit Jar file-->
        <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>
<!-- To download cucumber java Jar file-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
    </dependency>
<!-- To download cucumber api Jar file-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.4</version>
    </dependency>
<!-- To download cucumber Jvm deps file-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.5</version>
        </dependency>
<!-- To download cucumber junit file-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
        </dependency>
<!-- To download cucumber extentreport file-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vimalselvam</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-extentsreport</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
<!-- To download extent report file-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
        <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies> 
</project>
```

Comment: Try using the same version of dependencies for cucumber-core, cucumber-java, Cucumber-junit.  and also make sure src/java/test added as a source. Do a refresh and perform maven install.

Comment: Sorry ,Could you please explain how to change folder structure as src/java/test .Currently i have folder structure like below.     src/test/java

Comment: ya. my bad.. i meant src/test/java. did it work ?

Comment: No. I have used same version 1.2.5 for all 3 cucumber jar files. I'm using eclipse 2020 version and my step definition is already under src/test/java. But still i have this issue. Below is my runner file :package stepdefinations;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions; // import cucumber core jar file
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
  features={"src\\test\\resources\\feature"},
  glue ={"stepdefinations"}
    )
public class testRunner {
}

Comment: I have installed Java 8 version and all got resolved suddenly.

Answer (score 0):

I have installed Java 8 version and all got resolved suddenly.